# How to extract a string from a larger string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, extract

Using jQuery how would I find/extract the "Spartan" string if the outputted HTML page had the following..

```
<a href="/mytlnet/logout.php?t=e22df53bf4b5fc0a087ce48897e65ec0">
  <b>Logout</b>
</a> : Spartan<br>
```

Comment: Is there any other surrounding HTML? Is this in a div or a p or a td tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html). Or by [splitting the string](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) in a more tedious fashion.

Since I'm not a big regex-junkie, I would likely get the text-equivalent using .text(), then split the result on ":", and grab the second index (which would be the 'Spartan' text).

Comment: I would try to avoid regex in this case and try to use xpath or css selectors, then massage the data in the end. It should be more universal that way.

Answer (score 1):

if the pattern is going to be consistent you can your RegEx

or if the markup is going to be the same you can try the  [jQuery HTML Parser](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

As well as using regular expressions, I've also abusively used these functions to do the things it seems you want to do (strip html and such from a text string):

```
//removes all HTML tags
function striptags(stringToStrip) {
    return stringToStrip.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
}
//standard trim function for JavaScript--removes leading and trailing white space
function trim(stringToTrim) {
return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

Incredible regular expressions that have saved me a lot of time.